# filter view on modification date

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I found the way to filter a view by creation date ;

In the Search I put for example :
return "[_CreationDate] >" + fromDate +"'";

Is their a similar way to only get the documents from a certain modification date in my view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page in Domino Help entitled "How can I refine a search query using operators?" is very useful.

[_RevisionDate] is the internal field you want.

If using replicas, please note this gives the date the document was modified, not the date it was modified in this file (i.e. the date the updated document hit this replica).

Comment: Unfortunately the page is well hidden away in the Help, which is why I specifically cover it in my Notes Client cheat sheets